# After playing wav file, do I need to delete the buffer?

Tags: c++, c, audio, sdl, wav

I am trying to implement classes implementing the wav playing, as explained in [this example](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlconvertaudio.html). The relevant code part is here :

```
/* Setup for conversion */
wav_cvt.buf = malloc(wav_len * wav_cvt.len_mult);
wav_cvt.len = wav_len;
memcpy(wav_cvt.buf, wav_buf, wav_len);

/* We can delete to original WAV data now */
SDL_FreeWAV(wav_buf);

/* And now we're ready to convert */
SDL_ConvertAudio(&wav_cvt);
```

When a wav file finishes playing (I am not going to play it again), do I need to free the memory buffer that is malloc()-ed above? Or is it done automatically somewhere?

Comment: Whatever you malloc, you have to free. I am not sure of this specific case but in general this is the symantics.

Comment: This must be specified in the documentation of `SDL_FreeWAV()`, however it would be surprising (and quite asymetric) that `SDL` requires you to allocate manually but takes care of the deletion itself (how can it know how you allocated your memory ?)

Comment: @ereOn wav memory is allocated in `SDL_LoadWAV`, and freed with `SDL_FreeWAV`, but that is not what I am asking. Everything tells you (and @Armen) are right.

Comment: If you are using **classes** then why is this question tagged as **C**

Comment: @Tim Because the same thing is done for C. Should this malloc()-ed memory be free()-ed or not?

Comment: @VJo, yes, anything you malloc() yourself, you must free().

Comment: @Alex B: `s/must/almost always/` :P

Comment: @Matt So, I don't understand. Is it the case here or not?

Comment: @VJo: Here, the answer is yes. Since you malloc'd it yourself, you should free it yourself. See my answer for justifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, nothing is done automatically. You must free it.

Comment: I thought the same, but I couldn't find an example or a claim that would back it up. Can you provide a link which supports it?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that C (and anything of it's implementation) doesn't manage dynamic memory allocation automatically, whenever you have allocated some pieces of memory (mark the memory offset as USED), you should free() it when you are done to remark that offset as UNUSED. But that's not MUST!!!.

Comment: why is free(); ing it not a **must**

Comment: @Tim, well, it is not if you like to leak memory and be universally hated.

Answer (score 1):

Any [`malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) is generally [`free`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free)'d elsewhere by the same module. I say generally because you may never intend to give the memory back for performance or persistence reasons. Furthermore, memory allocations will be reclaimed by the operating system when the process terminates regardless You're not endangering the system.

Since **you** `malloc`ed the buf, you should actually `free` it yourself. Save [`SDL_FreeWav`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sdl_freewav) for wave buffers passed to you by SDL that you are done with (such as from [`SDL_LoadWav`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sdl_loadwav)).

Internal to `SDL_LoadWav`, will be a `malloc` call by SDL. `SDL_FreeWav` is a wrapper around the corresponding `free`. This allocate/deallocate function pairing is common as some libraries may implement custom memory management routines that resemble or wrap `malloc` and `free`. They may even open up new heap contexts that are not accessible from the standard functions, and intended to be private. There's not even a requirement that the memory be allocated on a heap, but this is orthogonal to your question.

It's likely that `SDL_FreeWav` is just a straight `free`, but when a library provides deallocation functions you should prefer those in case the behaviour differs.

When in doubt, always call the deallocation routine if you believe you're done with the memory resource. Double `free` errors are noisy and generally generate stack traces that will let you quickly identify the problem. Other libraries such as [glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/) will usually have built-in diagnostics that will alert you to overzealous deallocation. Deallocating aggressively also aids in locating logical errors: If you think you're done with the memory, but some other part of the program isn't, the resource use will need to be re-examined.